# how to have default label class, but different text per input in cakephp 2.x

Tags: forms, cakephp

I know you can define inputDefaults in the `Form->create` function, but if I define the label `class` there, and set the `text` in the individual `Form->input` function, the `class` option is removed. Is there any way around this or do I have to re-define the label option completely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've to redefine the label option completely.

```
$this->Form->input('name', array(
    'label' => array(
        'text' => __('label-text'),
        'class' => 'label-class'
    )
));
```

your default options are overridden by the options that you've specified for the input method of form helper.

For more information check [__parseOptions](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-FormHelper.html#__parseOptions)